# Auto-login into vendors ASP.Net application in my own environment

Tags: asp.net

I've got an Intranet that I manage, and we've just purchased some vendor's system that has no out-of-the-box LDAP/AD support. I think it's an ASP.Net application (there's a form on the login.aspx [hint1] that has id="aspnetForm" [hint2]), and I thought, in my perfectly-run imagination, that all I had to do was pass users credential in as parameters to the login page (I've injected their usernames into the vendor's database, and I can manually log in fine with those), and it just worked. Not so.

Uri looks something like this ; http://[apps_domain]/Controls/CtlLogin.aspx

I have no access to this ASP.Net environment, I can only access it through URI's, however I've got full access to another server on the environment on which I could run various scripts, preferably PHP (as we run a few other apps in PHP, and we've got people with those skills).

Is there some default way that ASP.Net delivers simple login to their apps? I'm using NTLM and AD elsewhere to validate the credentials, I just need to inject these into the ASP.Net app. I expected this to be simpler ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you like to implement it. Would you like the existing form-based logon but allow users to enter their AD credentials into the form (a la Outlook Web Access), or have the application instead make use of IIS/Windows NTLM or Kerberos Authentication done via HTTP headers (which is more secure as the user never needs to type in their username/password).

Without knowing more information about this application you've purchased, I cannot say. ASP.NET does provide a couple of backends for authentication but it's likely that this application rolls its own. If the application does use the stock "Membership" or web.config-defined authentication and membership system then it's *hypothetically* possible for you to change the web.config file to use an ActiveDirectory/Ldap/Kerberos provider instead of its own, however in my experience very few ASP.NET applications (outside trivial Hello, World-examples) use the Membership system by-the-book. Do not expect this to work, and you will need an in-depth knowledge of ASP.NET's Membership system. And as I said, all of this is based on the assumption your application uses Membership in the first place.

How do you intend your PHP scripts to work, exactly? Authentication works by having the client submit a form and the server responds with a cookie. You can't delegate those tasks - my guess is you'd have to proxy it, but then you're in for a world of hurt.

In short, I'd get in contact with the vendor and ask for a modification to allow for integration with your existing systems or get a refund.

Comment: Just accepted it since there seem to be no real answer to this. I'll chase up the Membership topic, however, even though I shouldn't need to muck about with these issues if the app was properly developed in the first place. :) It's kinda strange there is no common way for injecting usernames and passwords, as this would be the most common way of doing single-sign-on without too much change to application code. Hmm. Thanks for your time.